# MS ACCESS - Subform result not showing in Form

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have an unbound form (Master) containing 2 subforms. Under the Master form there is a textbox which is used as the master field, linking with respective child field under the subforms.

When I enter into the master field and requery, some results were not shown under the subforms, but when I open the respective subforms on the left panel, there is actual results shown inside the subform, but not displayed under the Master unbound form.

What is the likely  cause of this?

Comment: When opened directly, the (sub)forms are not filtered, thus you see (also) those records not filtered out by your master/child link fields.

Comment: Does that mean I have a wrongly linked master/child fields? How should I fix it?

Comment: I guess so. Remove then and check what is returned. Then adjust to the filtering you are after.

Comment: Removing the master/child field works, thanks a lot! Seems I'm not familiar with those settings. Thanks!

Comment: You should be. It is the core of the mainform/subform mechanics and saves a lot of code.